# String Operators

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im programming with visual basic 2010 express. I have list of strings on format like "GOOD          DAY" which have two words (on begining and on end) and 10 spaces between them. I want to get the words from that string. (I want to get GOOD and to get DAY). Which string operator may help me to success this easily. Thanks.

Comment: i can remove spaces, but how can i get the two words from string. I mean i want to  get GOOD and DAY

Comment: Fixed your tags - VBA is not VB.NET

Comment: In VB.NET Split() is a method of a string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trim` removes leading, lagging, and consecutive spaces from strings.
`Split` splits a string by a delimiter of your choice.

---

```
Dim MyString
MyString = Split(Trim("Good Day"), " ")

MsgBox MyString(0)
MsgBox MyString(1)
```